# How to convert columns from a csv file into arrays in python with the first value being the array variable name?

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I would like to convert columns from my csv file into arrays in python however I want the first value in each column (the first row) to be the array names.

I have tried this:

```
import csv

data = csv.reader(open('products.csv', 'r'), delimiter=",", quotechar='|')
column1, column2 = [], []

for row in data:
    column1.extend(row[0])
    column2.extend(row[1])

print(column1)
print(column2)
```

However, this gives it character by character and does not make the array name the first value.

Here is my csv file.

```
name,description,price
Apples,A bag of 3 apples,1.75
White Bread,A loaf of white bread,1.90
Wholemeal Bread,A loag of wholemeal bread,1.45
```

It needs to be expandable (Not hardcoded/I will add to this file later)

Expected results is 3 arrays.

```
name = []
description = []
price = []
```

and the values line up e.g. index 0 in all arrays will be the first column etc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a large number of samples in csv file and don't want to construct `DataFrame` object, you can use `csv` module and constract your lists in an iterable way without loading whole data in memory:

```
import csv

csv_file = 'sample.csv'

names = []
description = []
price = []

with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        names.append(row.get('name'))
        description.append(row.get('description'))
        price.append(row.get('price'))

print(names)
## ['Apples', 'White Bread', 'Wholemeal Bread']

print(description)
## ['A bag of 3 apples', 'A loaf of white bread', 'A loag of wholemeal bread']

print(price)
## ['1.75', '1.90', '1.45']
```

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend using a Pandas DataFrame for this. Do

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Then in your python code,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('products.csv')
```

In an interactive python console, you can explore the structure of this DataFrame

```
%% Get the 'name' column
df['name']

%% Get the 'description' column
description = df['description']

%% Get it in a numpy array
description = df['description'].values

%% Get the row named 'Apples'
Apples = df[df['name'] == 'Apples']
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the csv is

```
A, B, C
1, a, x
2, b, y
3, c, z
```

You can use `exec` to set up all the variables you need in a greater list.

Let's assume the lists are already constructed as the following

```
[[1, 2, 3], [a, b, c], [x, y, z]] # This should be fairly straightforward.
```

```
# data is the lists
# row is the first row
for i in range(len(row)):
   exec(row[i] + " = " + str(data[i]))

# Now all the variables should be defined 
# >>> A
# [1, 2, 3]
# ...
```

Comment: Do you know how to construct `row` and `data` in my code example?