# how to export a columns of CSV file as an arrays in python?

Tags: python, file, sorting

I have a CSV file containing 2 columns and 1000 lines, I want to export these 2 columns as 2 arrays, each array containing the column values. How can I get it done using Python?

Comment: What does "export as array" mean? I could see exporting as 2 CSV files. But arrays are in-memory things, not export things. There are a lot of examples out there for reading, manipulating and writing CSVs. Its best to get a script mostly working and ask questions if you have problems.

Comment: I tried this way and it worked with me https://stackoverflow.com/a/58178333/14599063

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip` on the iterable of rows returned by `csv.reader` to assemble the data into columns:

```
import csv
with open('example.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    columns_as_lists = [list(c) for c in zip(*reader)]
print(columns_as_lists[0])  # All the values in the first column of your CSV
print(columns_as_lists[1])  # All the values in the second column of your CSV
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use List Comprehension and loop trough the csv file in this way:

```
import csv 

with open('example.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    column1 = [row[0] for row in csv_reader]
    column2 = [row[1] for row in csv_reader]
```

Comment: `column2` will be an empty list here.   The first list comprehension exhausts the iterable `csv_reader`, so it has nothing to yield in the second list comprehension. `csv_reader` doesn't behave as a **list** of rows that can be repeatedly iterated over: it's a **generator** that yields rows.

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas for better performances and manipulation for future

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv("example.csv")

for row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the pandas and specifying the column names.

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("example.csv")
        
array1=df["col_name1"].values # as numpy array
array2=list(df["col_name2"].values) # as python array
```